# How to create a subscription with a different start price?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I am using subscriptions in my app and I want users to pay a different amount for the first subscription period than for the following periods.

For example: A one-year subscription which costs $499 in the first year and the following years it only costs $300.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You create a one-year auto-renewing subscription for whatever price the subscriptions should have after the first year and for this subscription you create a one-year pay-up-front introductory offer for $499.